# How to Calculate and Get Digit Using Module 11 Algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm trying to do a syntax cast where I have a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) function that calculates the check digit from an input number.

where the variables:

- **input** - is the input value (*Example: 200300*)
- **num_digits** - is the number of digits (*if defined 1, its respective digit will be 7; already defined it 2, its respective digit will be 70. According to the input value*)
- **limit** - is the multiplication limit (*in my case I need it to be multiplied by/up to 9*)
- **x10** - in this case being true or false, being true the digit will be multiplied by 10

all variables mentioned above refer to my JavaScript function:

```js
function calcDigitMod11(input, num_digits, limit, x10) {
    var mult, sum, i, n, digit;
    if (!x10) num_digits = 1;

    for (n = 1; n <= num_digits; n++) {
        sum = 0; mult = 2;
        for (i = (input.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
            sum += (mult * parseInt(input.charAt(i)));
            if (++mult > limit) mult = 2;
        }

        if (x10) {
            digit = ((sum * 10) % 11) % 10;
        } else {
            digit = sum % 11;
            if (digit == 10) digit = 'x';
        }

        input += (digit);
    }

    return input.substring((input.length - num_digits), num_digits);
}
```

in short, my big problem is to create this same function in the [php](/questions/tagged/php) syntax

If you print the function's return on the console, passing the following parameters: `calcDigitMod11(200300, 1, 9, true);` your return must be the check digit

> 7

### giving an applied...

"tried" to convert syntaxes using the same variables, parameters, among others

```php
function calcDigitMod11($input, $num_digits, $limit, $x10) {
    $mult; $sum; $i; $n; $digit;
    if (!$x10) $num_digits = 1;

    for ($n = 1; $n <= $num_digits; $n++) {
        $sum = 0; $mult = 2;
        for ($i = (strlen($input) - 1); $i >= 0; $i--) {
            $sum += ($mult * (int)$input[$i]);
            if ((++$mult) > $limit) $mult = 2;
        }

        if ($x10) {
            $digit = (($sum * 10) % 11) % 10;
        } else {
            $digit = $sum % 11;
            if ($digit == 10) $digit = 'x';
        }

        $input += ($digit);
    }

    return substr($input, strlen($input) - $num_digits, $num_digits);
}
```

I wrote an `echo calcDigitMod11(200300, 1, 9, true);` but it returns the digit to me.

> 0

I didn't find where the mistaken point **x** is, I don't know if I'm running away from logic! Here is a table of the `JavaScript` function of the true digits according to the input value:

- `calcDigitMod11(200300, 1, 9, true);` is return **7**
- `calcDigitMod11(200301, 1, 9, true);` is return **5**
- `calcDigitMod11(200302, 1, 9, true);` is return **3**
- `calcDigitMod11(200303, 1, 9, true);` is return **1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, you can retrieve characters using index values only for strings. Example:

```
$str = "98765";
echo $str[1]; // will return 8
```

If we do the same for integers it will throw a warning.

```
$num = 98765;
echo $num[1];

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type int
```

To enable errors/warnings in your script, add the below code at the top of your php file

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Now, to fix your algorithm, we can use `str_split` to convert the integer values into an array before using index to extract digits.

```
<?php
function calcDigitMod11($input, $num_digits, $limit, $x10) {
    $mult; $sum; $i; $n; $digit;
    if (!$x10) $num_digits = 1;

    for ($n = 1; $n <= $num_digits; $n++) {
        $sum = 0; $mult = 2;
        $input_arr = str_split($input); // Convert string to an array
        for ($i = (strlen($input) - 1); $i >= 0; $i--) {
            $sum += ($mult * $input_arr[$i]); // Use array to fetch digits
            if ((++$mult) > $limit) $mult = 2;
        }

        if ($x10) {
            $digit = (($sum * 10) % 11) % 10;
        } else {
            $digit = $sum % 11;
            if ($digit == 10) $digit = 'x';
        }

        $input += ($digit);
    }

    echo "<br/><br/>True Digit=$digit<br/>";

    return substr($input, strlen($input) - $num_digits, $num_digits);
}


echo "Output=" . calcDigitMod11(200300, 1, 9, true);
echo "Output=" . calcDigitMod11(200301, 1, 9, true);
echo "Output=" . calcDigitMod11(200302, 1, 9, true);
echo "Output=" . calcDigitMod11(200303, 1, 9, true);
?>
```

Output:

```
True Digit=7
Output=7

True Digit=5
Output=6

True Digit=3
Output=5

True Digit=1
Output=4
```

[Working Demo](https://extendsclass.com/php-bin/e632b1a)

Comment: Why is it that when I print ```echo calcDigitMod11(200300, 2, 9, true);``` which was supposed to return **70** it returns **11**?

Comment: 11 is correct as per the algorithm because it will loop twice as per `$num_digits`

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: you just helped a brazilian!